# What is the hive command to see the value of hive.exec.dynamic.partition

Tags: hive, beeline, hivecli, hive-configuration

We know that set command is used to set some values for properties

```
 hive> SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
 hive> SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=non-strict;
```

But how do we read the current value of above property

I tried the below commands, its not working

```
 get hive.exec.dynamic.partition
 show hive.exec.dynamic.partition
```

Could someone help on getting the correct hive command to read the current value of those above properties .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The same `SET` command but without value assignment will print current value:

```
hive> SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition;
```

Output:

```
hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true
```

`SET` command without variable prints a list of configuration variables that are overridden.

See the documentation on [Hive CLI](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli) and [Beeline](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-Beeline%E2%80%93CommandLineShell)

Answer (score 0):

To check property: hive.exec.dynamic.partition

Run below command
 SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition;
 SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode;

and you can also visit below link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-HiveConfigurationProperties